# Why is the CG Path always fading out?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a weird issue with some basic drawing code here:

[image: This is a single stroke of one of the many in the for-loop]

The code for this is just the following in a for-loop, I just want to draw some vertical lines into the view:

```
     UIBezierPath* verticalLine = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [verticalLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(currentXPosition, 0)];
    [verticalLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(currentXPosition, self.frame.size.height)];
    [verticalLine closePath];
    verticalLine.lineWidth = 1;
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [verticalLine stroke];
```

I can't imagine a reason for it. Can you?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

EDIT: Drawing horizontal lines works perfectly well, they have normal width and don't fade out.

Comment: Before I look too closely at your code... what were you expecting it to look like?

Comment: I want it to be a single, sharp 1px-line ;)

Comment: I think the problem is probably with some of the code you didn't paste.  Are you modifying the graphics state somehow?  What are the values of currentXPosition?  What do you get if you only try drawing one line?

Comment: Nope, not modifying it anywhere. It's not about currentXPosition, drawing a single line results in the same...

Comment: Well, in fact I am adding some UIViews containing some CALayers later... Does that matter?

Comment: OK, think i got it, though not having a solution: The view resizes it's own frame since it is a subview of a UIScrollView. If I remove this code, the whole thing works...

Comment: That makes sense. Your 1-pixel line is being scaled up with interpolation, making it fuzzy.